# Can a function and its Fourier transform be polynomial decay simultaneously? Is this function class dense in a certain space?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, fourier-transform

I have a subgaussian r.v. with pdf $p(x) \in SG(a,C)$, where $SG(a,C)$ is the set of pdf of all random variables $X \in \mathbb R^d$ s.t. $\mathbb E e^{aX^2} < C,$ i.e. a set of subgaussian pdf.

I wanna characterize some property of $p$. What I can do is that my result has already held for function in $\mathcal F(k,L)$, where
$$
\mathcal F(k,L) = \{f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)\bigcap L^2(\mathbb R^d):f \text{ is continuous}, \|f|x|^k\|_1\leq L,\|\hat f |x|^k \|_1 \leq L\} .
$$
Here $\hat f$ is the fourier transform of $f$, and $k>0,L>0$. This function class has the property that both itself and fourier transform decay polynomial. Of course, $p$ might not be in $\mathcal F(k,L)$ since it's fourier transform might be smooth.

**My questions:**

Given $a>0,C>0$, is it possible that there exists $k,L$ (relevant to $a,C$), so that $\mathcal F(k,L)$ is dense in $SG(a,C)$ with norm $\| \cdot\|_1$? In other words, there exists $\{f_n\} \in \mathcal F(k,L)$, so that $\|f_n - p\|_1 \to 0$?

Comment: "Of course, p might not be in F(k,L) since it's fourier transform might be smooth."

No! 
If your function is smooth, then its Fourier transform decays fast, and so in particular, $\|\hat{f}|x|^k\| < C$

Comment: @LL3.14 What I mean is that if the funtion is NOT smooth, then its fourier might NOT decay fast (which can happen for a general pdf). What's your opinion about this statement?